# Create a DataGridView with ComboBoxColumn from a DataTable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datatable, datagridviewcombobox

I have a `DataGridView` that I would like to fill programmatically. By creating a `DataTable` and binding it through a `BindingSource` to a `DataGridView`, the columns in the `DataGridView` are created as `TextBoxColumns`. A code sample below:

```
Dim dataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
dataTable.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("TextBoxColumn1"),
                                             New DataColumn("TextBoxColumn2"),
                                             New DataColumn("ComboBoxColumn"),
                                             New DataColumn("TextBoxColumn3"),
                                             New DataColumn("TextBoxColumn4")})

Dim bindingSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource
bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource
```

What is the best way to make the column **"ComboBoxColumn"** a `ComboBoxColumn` in the `DataGridView`?

I could create a `ComboBoxColumn` in the `DataGridView` manually and then bind it to a `DataColumn`, but I would like to know if there's a better way, like setting a property in the `DataColumn` or something like that.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7471347/209668) shows how to add a [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx) to your `dataGridView`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for because the columns in the `DataGridView` are created when the grid is bound to data; I don't add them myself

Comment: Of course, I could maybe replace the auto generated column later on.

Comment: That's how I would suggest you do it. Grab it by name then replace it with a new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Codesleuth's suggestion, I replaced the auto generated `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` with a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` like this:

```
Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "ComboBoxColumn"
comboBoxColumn.DataSource = comboBoxBindingSource
comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "ComboBoxColumn"
comboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "ComboBoxColumn"
DataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(COLUMN_INDEX)
DataGridView.Columns.Insert(COLUMN_INDEX, comboBoxColumn)
```

Comment: you should accept this answer even though it was your own to help show that it has been solved. Thanks!